# which is best js libraray for mobile app jquery or angular.js?

Tags: jquery, css, html, angularjs, cordova

I want to create an app in phonegap. I want to choose any js library for simple but attractive html/css/js app. Any one can suggest which is best regarding to event effects,processing time and good user interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try angularjs and [topcoat.io](http://topcoat.io/), effects can be found here https://github.com/topcoat/topcoat-effeckt

But the decision to use angularjs and topcoat or not depends on your problem. 
So just start some PoC to see if the library fits your needs

Comment: your provided link http://topcoat.io/ is great!

Answer (score 1):

you can use jqm for crossmobile platform : http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/ -demos and

http://jquerymobile.com/.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using phonegap and for UI i would suggest you use jquery mobile, also you will get support lib in jquery mobile a  lot .

http://jquerymobile.com/download/